# Why Acme is using own uniform initializer?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, tensorflow, weights-initialization, deepmind

Why is Acme using own initializer for both tanh and ELU, when commonly used for tanh is Xavier and for ELU is He initializer? What mathematics is behind them?

[Here](https://github.com/deepmind/acme/blob/master/acme/tf/networks/continuous.py) is the code.

```
uniform_initializer = tf.initializers.VarianceScaling(
    distribution='uniform', mode='fan_out', scale=0.333)
```